# Global Error Handling in Task.Run for realtime User ntofication

Tags: wpf, error-handling, task

I have a wpf c# app.

I normally use a global error handler to catch all errors:

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString(), "Error",
          MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error)));
        e.Handled = true;
        InformedWorkerDataService.Common.Shared.RecordMessage(e.Exception.ToString(), true);
    }
    finally { }
}
```

However, if start off a task.run 'bit of code' and it throws an error then i have observed that error is not caught:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    throw and error here    
});
```

so I have to put a 'Try-Catch' thing in to capture it:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        throw an error here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        do  something with error
    }
});
```

~ which defeats the object of having a Global Error handler
But, if i use this approach:

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, e) => {
    e.Exception  //The Exception that went unobserved.
    e.SetObserved(); //Marks the Exception as "observed," thus preventing it from triggering exception escalation policy which, by default, terminates the process.
};
```

... it will do my global exception handling but if I want to notify the user of the error real-time it does not do so very well because IT IS on a separate thread.

What would be a good compromise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` is not guarenteed to fire in real time with the exception being thrown. This means that using this handler for user notification can be quite confusing as the user action and error notification will not happen synchronously. For user driven handling of 'unexpected' task exceptions, you could create helper methods as below and use `TaskEx.Run` instead of `Task.Run`:

```
public static class TaskEx
{
    public static Task Run(Action function)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                function();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TraceEx.TraceException(ex);
                //Dispatch your MessageBox etc.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Obviously this is not as simple as adding a global handler (which should still be done for tracing purposes) but is simple enough to implement in UI driven code.